# How to access parent variable on require module node

Tags: javascript, object, module, parent, require

how i can access to parent variable on exports module?

```
function ThunderClient(key){//my class
    this.key = key //i want have access to this variable
}

ThunderClient.prototype.users = require('./modules/users')(route_rest,this.key); //this.key are key of ThunderClient

ThunderClient.prototype.address = require('./modules/address')(route_rest,this.key);//this.key are key of ThunderClient
```

> require('./modules/address')(route_rest,this.key);

this.key is a key of ThunderClient (on construct i fill this variable).
On my module users i want have access to this.key of ThunderClient but if i use "this.key" on require doesn't work, how i can this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish with the assignment to the prototype. The assignment happens when the function is **defined**, i.e. **before** `ThunderClient` is called. `this` doesn't refer to an instance because it doesn't exist at that moment, so no, `this.key` *does not* refer to the `key` you are setting in the constructor. Maybe have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript to make yourself more familiar with constructors first.

Comment: another option to assign an external variable in the constructor, but when I called the first instance to the functions require, you know how to order the call of functions to make the instance (the constructor is executed first)? (excuse my English am using the translator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your imported functions at the top:

```
var users = require('./modules/users');
var address = require('./modules/address');
```

Then just wrap those imported functions:

```
ThunderClient.prototype.users = function(){ return users(route_rest, this.key); }
ThunderClient.prototype.address = function(){ return address(route_rest, this.key); }
```

If you want to have instance specific `users` assigned at creation then you'll need to add them to the created instance inside your constructor and not in the prototype.

```
function ThunderClient(key){
    this.key = key;
    this.users = users(route_rest, this.key);
    this.address = address(route_rest, this.key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The lines `ThunderClient.prototype.users = require('...')` and `ThunderClient.prototype.address` are being executed in the global scope, instead of an instance of your `ThunderClient` module.

for example: `ThunderClient.prototype.users = require('./modules/users')(route_rest,this.key);`
In a Web Browser, `this` would be `window`, meaning you are checking `window.key` instead of doing something like this:

```
ThunderClient.prototype.getKey = function() {
    return this.key; // here, 'this' is definitely our module instance
};
var client = new ThunderClient('abc');
console.log(client.getKey); // abc
```